# Did the idea for Wolverine come from Enter the Dragon?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

I was watching Enter The Dragon (1973) for the first time and I noticed something.

[image: Mr Han from Enter the Dragon (1973) with blades instead of a hand]

Was that the first Wolverine? Was the real one copied from Mr.Han?

Comment: Possible, wolverene first appeared in 1974

Comment: [The Craw?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftgAG3Vnif8)

Comment: Bagh nakh go back for at least some centuries before Enter the Dragon, so if it was inspired by a weapon in another medium, there are other possible sources.

Comment: @Machavity The Craw is not as similar as Enter the Dragon to Wolverine

Comment: @StrangePhoton Was kidding. Hence why it's a comment

Answer (score 11):

> Marvel editor-in-chief Roy Thomas asked writer Len Wein to devise a character specifically named Wolverine, who is Canadian and of small stature and with a wolverine's fierce temper. John Romita, Sr. designed the first Wolverine costume, and believes he introduced the retractable claws, saying, "When I make a design, I want it to be practical and functional. I thought, 'If a man has claws like that, how does he scratch his nose or tie his shoelaces?'

This is from the Wikipedia page for Wolverine [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character)). Originally Wolverine was supposed to be a mutated wolverine, but this later changed to a young adult with claws, and then early drawings caused the character to be made older, approximately 40-60 years old.

There's no mention of Mr. Han in the thought process for Wolverine. The claws were probably a main stay from the idea of a feral mutated wolverine and as the quote says, were made retractable to make the character idea practical.

Comment: *Originally Wolverine was supposed to be a mutated wolf* The funny thing is that wolves and more broadly *Canidae* don't have retractable claws, while *Felidae* do. But calling him... "Catherine" would have somewhat lessened his fierceness

Comment: @Sekhemty indeed, however as you can see from the quote, the _retractable_ part was an afterthought.

Comment: Yes, of course, mine was just a joke :)

Comment: Yeah I know ;), funny that Sabretooth didn't have retractable claws, his razor sharp nails were always on show, and yet a Sabretooth is an ancestor of the feline family. They got them the wrong way around.

Comment: IIRC, it was fairly long after he was introduced that it was made clear that the claws were actually part of him and not part of the gloves, but I have yet to find an actual citation that such ambiguity was intentional.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots there is a middle step where the claws are part of the adamantium skeleton, but not part of his bones

Comment: @FuzzyBoots not _absolutely_ sure this is the first reference, but no more than 16 months later, in X-Men#98, he "pops" his claws and it is shown that they are part of his body and not part of the gloves/costume

Comment: @Kevin: That's where CBR says it was revealed too (http://www.cbr.com/the-abandoned-an-forsaked-are-wolverines-claws-part-of-his-mutation-or-what/)

Comment: *Originally Wolverine was supposed to be a mutated wolf* - mutated *wolverine*, not wolf. (I mean, hence the name.) And that claim was always denied by the late Len Wein, the character's co-creator.

Comment: @Sekhemty: Wolverines are mustelids, not canids. (But mustelids still don't have retractable claws.)